# CSS e JS não estão sendo aplicados ao projeto em Spring MVC (config via java)

Tags: java, css, mvc, aplicação-web, spring

Sou iniciante com o SpringMVC e estou aprendendo através do livro Spring MVC (Domine o principal framework web java, por Alberto Souza, casa do código).

Antes de começar com o Spring, criei um projeto Maven e implementei o frontend e a parte da persistência com jpa + hibernate. Até aí tudo bem, importei o projeto pra o STS (Spring Tool Suite) e comecei a realizar as configurações explicadas no livro. Porém quando finalizei a configuração AppWebConfiguration (segue código abaixo), o meu CSS e JS não estavam sendo aplicados mais.

Já pesquisei no google, no livro, aqui no stackoverflow; até implementei algumas possíveis soluções e o erro persiste. O projeto sobe, funciona normalmente, porém sem css e sem javascript. Segue abaixo o que eu implementei como tentativas para solucionar o problema.

**Segue abaixo os códigos implementados**

Código da classe com o método AppWebConfiguration

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.projetoAnuncio")
public class AppWebConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }


}
```

1º tentativa - implementar WebMvcConfig com extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.projetoAnuncio")
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping resourceHandlerMapping() {
        AbstractHandlerMapping handlerMapping = (AbstractHandlerMapping) super.resourceHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    // equivalent for <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> tag
    @Override
     public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
         configurer.enable();
     }

}
```

2º Tentativa - implementar SecurityConfiguration com extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");    
    }

}
```

**Abaixo segue algumas Imagens para melhor entendimento**

Meu package explorer

[image: Meu package explorer]

Meu head

[image: Meu head]

Na url já tentei colocar o '/resources/' na frente, mas não resultou em nada.

O projeto é para a última atividade de uma disciplina na faculdade. Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda, então meio que urgente porque preciso terminar essa semana.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Não coloque no texto/título da pergunta a palavra resolvido, marque antes sim a resposta que resolveu o seu problema como certa.

Comment: @JorgeB. Como fui eu mesmo que consegui solucionar o problema, não consigo marcar como resposta certa uma resposta minha. O que fazer?

Comment: Jocsâ consegues sim marcar uma resposta tua como certa, tens é de esperar 2 dias se não me engano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Galera, continuei a procurar conteúdo que me ajudasse e encontrei os seguintes passos que solucionou meu problema.

1º Criar a pasta 'resources' dentro de WebContent/webapp

2º Colar o conteúdo html e/ou css e/ou javascript e/ou whatever

3º Importar as tags do Spring

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
```

4º Incluir o import dentro da sua página, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/_css/yourStyle.css" var="yourStyleCSS"></spring:url>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${yourStyleCSS}" />
```

5º Implementar as seguinte classe com seus métodos no seu package de configuração:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.projetoAnuncio")
public class AppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    // INICIO - essa parte foi a que fez o meu projeto quebrar
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
    // FIM - essa parte foi a que fez o meu projeto quebrar

    // equivalents for <mvc:resources/> tags
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    // equivalent for <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> tag
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    //retorna um objeto de HandlerMapping que é necessário (não me pergunte o pq rsrs)
    @Override
    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping resourceHandlerMapping() {
        AbstractHandlerMapping handlerMapping = (AbstractHandlerMapping) super.resourceHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
        return handlerMapping;
    }

}
```

links de onde busquei as informações:

1 - [How to use spring MVC's  tag in a java application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299149/how-to-use-spring-mvcs-mvcresources-tag-in-a-java-application-context)
2 - [Spring MVC 4.2.2 – Best way to Add/Integrate JS, CSS and images into JSP file using ‘mvc:resources mapping’](http://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-4-2-2-best-way-to-integrate-js-and-css-file-in-jsp-file-using-mvcresources-mapping/)

Para concluir a configuração inicial básica do spring via java é necessário implementar a classe abaixo também.

```
public class ServletSpringMCV extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[]{AppWebConfiguration.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new String[] { "/" };
        }


    }
```

Precisei apenas disso para resolver o problema.